# How to fetch last row using distinct and group by same column

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve balance of last row from table  using distinct accountid from last ledgerid

```
|---ledgerid---|--accountid--|--blance--|
|     1        |      1      |    500   |
|     2        |      1      |    800   |
```

i want output as

```
|---ledgerid---|--accountid--|--blance--|
|     2        |      1      |    800   |
```

Comment: Which version of SQL are you actually using?

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.16-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)

Comment: You're familiar with ORDER BY and LIMIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give row number based on `accountid` and in the descending order of `ledgerid`.

**Query**

```
select t2.`ledgerid`,
       t2.`accountid`,
       t2.`blance`
from (
   select `ledgerid`,
   `accountid`,
   `blance`, ( 
       case `accountid`
       when @curA
       then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
       else @curRow := 1 and @curA := `accountid` end
     ) as `rn`
     from `your_table_name` t,
     (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r
     order by `accountid`, `ledgerid` desc
)t2
where t2.`rn` = 1;
```

**[Find demo here](http://rextester.com/GUXZD49060)**

Answer (score 1):

Try using the partition by as below.

```
select * from(select *
,row_number()over(partition by accountid order by ledgerid desc) r 
from
[yourtable])
where r=1
order by accountid
```

The above query is for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

In case your ledger ID is keep on incrementing by 1 then you can use the below query to fetch the last row:------

```
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY LEDGERID DESC
```

OR

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY LEDGERID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: there is also other account id so i cant do that this is the format of data in table

Comment: So you will put where condition of account id in query. For example:  SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY LEDGERID DESC LIMIT 1 WHERE account id = @accountID

Answer (score 0):

Try this:      -

`select * from table_name where accountid=1 order by legerid desc limit 1`

Comment: there is also other account id so i cant do that this is the format of data in table

Comment: How about this: select balance from test where legerid in (select max(legerid) from test group by accountid);

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l1.* FROM ledger l1 LEFT JOIN ledger l2 ON 
(l1.accountid = l2.accountid AND l1.ledgerid < l2.ledgerid) 
 WHERE l2.ledgerid IS NULL
```